# How to change value of Prograssbar in setup progress dialog on execution of Managed Code Custom Action in basic MSI project?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I am executing a managed code custom action while installation, but it doesn't change the value of progressbar in setup progress dialog...

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with managed code. The installation progress bar can be affected only from a custom action which receives an installation handle. So a [win32 DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) or VBScript.

You can find a tutorial here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367525%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: InstallShield's Managed Code Custom Action support can pass the installation handle. So while you're right about Installer Classes, you may be wrong about this case.